# Create a list depending on the values of another list c#

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to create a list of strings that would correspond with an existing list I already have created. My current function looks like:

```
public List<string> HeatGet(int HeatNumbers, List<string> List)
    {
        string HeatString;
        List<string> HeatStringList = new List<string>();
        int ListLength = List.Count;
        int HeatAssignValue = ListLength / HeatNumbers;

        for (int i = 0; i < ListLength; i++)
        {
            HeatString = "T" + i;

        }


        return HeatStringList;


    }
```

I would like the list to be split up into segments depending on HeatNumbers and each list will then include a value based on that, for example if my list has 10 entries and HeatNumbers is 2, then the first 5 values of the new list should have T1 and the last 5 values should have T2. However HeatNumbers is user defined and is subject to change.

EDIT:
If HeatNumbers = 2

List1 = {John, Alex, Harry, James, George, Joanne}
List2 = {T1, T1, T1, T2, T2, T2}

Comment: i did not understand how the final list should look like write it like that: 

list1: `first,sec,third`
list2: `first,sec,third`

Comment: @OrenHaliva Updated to show the lists

Comment: what should happend when the first list size is 5 and heatsnumber is 2?

Comment: Three to the top, two to the bottom, although it doesnt really matter which way it rounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just needed an algorithem to calculate the segment:

```
public List<string> HeatGet(int heatNumbers, List<string> list)
    {
        List<string> heatStringList = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            heatStringList.Add("T" + Math.Ceiling((i + 1) *  (float)heatNumbers / list.Count));
        }
        return heatStringList;
    }
```